# Can I get the result as empty cells (no value in the cell) If the value of the cell is empty in the tabular column?( IFERROR AND VLOOKUP ARE COMBINED)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

GOOGLE SPREAD SHEET 2 ( TABLE )

```
S.NO....NAME.............ID

1.     **(emptycell)**  (emptycell)     
2.      ELANGO N         1001      
3.      RAJA E           1002      
4.      RAJINI S         1003
```

My formula is ( using CellA6 as search box in googlespread sheet 1)

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13xiSA0hIJx2inhykUSRIi1pqfKJakMTu42Atj9Q-NCM/edit#gid=0","Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5"),3,0),  "NO SUCH NAME")

CELL A6 IS THE SEARCH CELL IN SHEET 1

IN GOOGLE SPREAD SHEET 1 IN **A6** CELL,

WHEN I TYPE NAME PRESENT IN THE TABLE I CAN GET **ID** AS A RESULT.

WHEN I TYPE THE NAME WHICH ARE NOT PRESENT IN THE TABLE  I CAN GET **"NO SUCH NAME"** AS A RESULT.

IF I HAVE N'T TYPE ANY IN NAME IN **CELL A6( SEARCH CELL )**, I CAN GET THE RESULT **"NO SUCH NAME"**

**Can I GET IF **CELL A6 IS EMPTY** THE RESULT ALSO WILL BE **EMPTY CELL**  ?**
( I have started to learn this kind of stuff from this month .This forum may belongs to genius. And also I am new to this website. If I make any mistakes pls forgive me )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(A6="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6, 
 IMPORTRANGE("13xiSA0hIJx2inhykUSRIi1pqfKJakMTu42Atj9Q-NCM", 
 "Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5"),3,0), "NO SUCH NAME"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a `QUERY` formula. There are 2 advantages for using `QUERY`:

1. If you dont remember the full name you can type in `Sheet1!A6` only part of names
2. the QUERY can be case insensitive so you can type in upper or lower
   case in `Sheet1!A6`

Copy and paste the following formula to the cell in `Sheet 1` where you want your search result answer. Ideally in `B6` (can be anywhere BUT `A6` where you have the search query cell):

```
=IFNA(
    IF($A$6="","",
        IFS(
            COUNTA(QUERY(Sheet2!A2:C,"select C where lower(B) contains lower('"&$A$6&"')",0))=1,QUERY(Sheet2!A2:C,"select C where lower(B) contains lower('"&$A$6&"')",0),
            COUNTA(QUERY(Sheet2!A2:C,"select C where lower(B) contains lower('"&$A$6&"')",0))>1,COUNTA(QUERY(Sheet2!A2:C,"select C where lower(B) contains lower('"&$A$6&"')",0))&" MATCHES"
        )
    ),
"NO SUCH NAME")
```

Whet this formula will do is take any letter combination typed in the cell `Sheet1!A6`, then perform a search in the table in `Sheet2!` (not the first row).

If `Sheet1!A6` is empty, the formula will return empty.

If `Sheet1!A6` contains a single match, it will return the `ID`

If there is no match with `Sheet1!A6`, it will return `NO SUCH NAME`

Now here I added one more case...

If `Sheet1!A6` contains a combination of characters which match with 2 or more names, the formula will count how many names match and will return `X MATCHES`